Is it possible to hide specific files uploaded to a Facebook Group page so that only those listed as admin. can see them?
One way that I am using a Facebook Group page is to help keep our huge family connected.  We also use it to announce family events such as our annual Family reunion, birth and death announcements, and to post our quarterly family newsletter.  Our family reunion has an organizational chart and chairpersons in which we also use our group account to exchange documents to one another that not all members need to have access to, such as proposals of changes in bylaws, etc.
We want to have specific files to be only visible to the chairpersons, which I shall make as administrators to the group account.
How do I hide the files that I upload without having it to also make a post, announcing it to all members of the group? And how do I make those files only visible to admins of the group page?

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?
